Why TypePiracy warning in Juila?
The code below shows warning, why? And how to implement it without warning?
An imported function has been extended without using 
module defined typed arguments.Julia(TypePiracy)

import Base: fill

fill(f::Function, length::Int) = [f(i) for i in 1:length] # <= warn

println(fill(1, 3))
println(fill((i) -> i^2, 3))

P.S.
Also, is there a way to differentiate fn with single int arg and no args, to make following code work:
println(fill(1, 3))
println(fill((i) -> i^2, 3))
println(fill(() -> 1, 3)) # <= Error


Does https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#avoid-type-piracy answer your question?

You defined a function defined in Base with types also defined in Base. None of your own types are used in this definition.

@BallpointBen I thought function defined without module, by default belongs to the implicit Main module? So there should be no conflict, or not?

You are adding a definition to Base.fill, which doesn't belong to Main

@BallpointBen thanks, got it, but... how are you supposed to define new functions then? I want to use both fill((i) -> i^2, 3) and fill(1, 3) and I don't want to call the second one as Base.fill(1, 3). How it's supposed to be achieved without type piracy?

You can use a name other than fill, a type other than Function (such as a simple wrapper), or just accept the type piracy. Or, in this case, just use map(f, 1:n) or f.(1:n).

@BallpointBen thanks, these are nice map(f, 1:n), f.(1:n). Using other function name doesn't make any sense, as the whole point of using Julia is clean code with multi dispatch. I guess I had to accept type piracy.
